# My completion handler always returns an empty array, why?

Tags: swift, firebase

I have the following function which fetches data from Firebase, fills a `compliments` array and is suppose to pass the array back via the completion `handler`.

The array that is returned is always empty even though objects are added to it?

Have I placed the completion handler code in the wrong location, I have tried inserting within all the curly braces and nothing works.

Break point at `handler(compliments, true)` execution line outputs this:

```
0x0000000102bb3fe8 vipeeps`partial apply forwarder for closure #1 (Swift.Array<Any>, Swift.Bool) -> () in vipeeps.ConversationsListVC.loadNewInvitesData() -> () at ConversationsListVC.swift
```

Function:

```
    func getComplimentsReceived(forUserId forId: String, handler: @escaping (_ complimentPack: [[String : Any]] ,_ success: Bool) -> ()){

    var compliments = [[String : Any]]()//empty array to hold compliments

    REF_USERS_COMPLIMENTS.child(forId).observe(.value) { (snapshot) in


       for item in snapshot.children{


        let itemSnap = item as! DataSnapshot


        let dict = itemSnap.value as! [String : Bool]


        for (key, status) in dict {

            switch status {

            case true:
                //print(status)

                self.REF_USERS.child(snapshot.key).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

                    let uid = snapshot.key
                    let name = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "name").value as! String
                    let email = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "email").value as! String
                    let profilePictureURL = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "profilePictureURL").value as! String

                    let birthday = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "birthday").value as! String
                    let firstName = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "firstName").value as! String
                    let lastName = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "lastName").value as! String
                    let gender = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "gender").value as! String
                    let discoverable = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "discoverable").value as! Bool
                    let online = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "online").value as! Bool

                    let discoveryPrefs = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "discoveryPrefs").value as! [String : Any]

                    let dictionary: [String : Any] = ["uid": uid, "name": name, "email": email, "profilePictureURL": profilePictureURL, "birthday": birthday, "firstName": firstName, "lastName": lastName, "gender": gender, "discoverable": discoverable, "online": online, "discoveryPrefs": discoveryPrefs]

                    let user = User(uid: uid, dictionary: dictionary)

                    let complimentPack = [
                        "type": "compliment",
                        "complimentId": key,
                        "active": status,
                        "fromUser": user
                        ] as [String : Any]

                    compliments.append(complimentPack)

                    print("compliments.count: \(compliments.count)")


                })//end observer

            case false:
                print(status)

                break

            }//end switch

         }//end for dict

       }//end for snapshot.item

      handler(compliments, true)

    }//end observe

 }//end func
```

Data structure:

[image]

Comment: This code won't work as expected anyway because you call the final `handler(..)` statement before the inner (asynchronous) closures are called. By the way: Why do you declare `compliments` and the array parameter as unspecified `[Any]` although you clearly know that's more specified `[[String:Any]]`?? And the Swift 3+ syntax for a closure is `@escaping ([Any] , Bool) -> ()` without underscores and parameter labels.

Comment: call the handler from inside 'end observe' scope not inside 'end for snapshot.item' scope and try !

Comment: thanks @vadian I have made the changes you suggested.

Comment: thanks @vivekDas tried that but still no luck :( I have edited my question with the latests code.

Comment: @vivekDas I was hoping you could elaborate on your comment about "the final handler(..) statement before the inner (asynchronous) closures are called", based on the console output print-lines I can see that they are not being output to the console in the order that I expect. I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: `observeSingleEvent` works asynchronously. The loop is executed instantly and `handler(..)` is called a long time (in terms of computer speed) before the first closure passes its `snapshot`.

Comment: @vadian is correct, i didn't see the wood for the trees. You might want to work with dispatch groups to get informed when all your inner async observers have finished.

Comment: oh ok @vadian that makes sense. Any suggestions to my code that I could make to achieve my objective? or are you able to point me in the right direction please?

Comment: thanks @AndreasOetjen Im still new to Swift (coding in general) are you able to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use dispatch groups, which will be notfied once all your async `observeSingelEvent` calls have been finished:

- In your `observe` code, you create a new `DispatchGroup`
- Before calling the async `observeSingleEvent`, you `enter` the group.
- At the end of the asyc closure, you `leave` the group
- Once all `enters` and `leave` calls match, `notify` will be called, which then calls the `handler`

See here:

```
func getComplimentsReceived(forUserId forId: String, handler: @escaping (_ complimentPack: [Any] ,_ success: Bool) -> ()){
    REF_USERS_COMPLIMENTS.child(forId).observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
        var compliments = [Any]()//empty array to hold compliments
        let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
        for item in snapshot.children {

            for (key, status) in dict {

                switch status {
                    case true:
                        dispatchGroup.enter()
                        self.REF_USERS.child(snapshot.key).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                            // ...
                            compliments.append(complimentPack)
                            dispatchGroup.leave()
                    })//end observer
                    case false:
                        print(status)
                        break

                }//end switch

            }//end for dict

        } //end for snapshot.item

        dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
            handler(compliments, true)
        }
    } //end observe

}//end func
```

Addition Edit func (by @Roggie):

```
func loadNewInvitesData(){


    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }

    DataService.run.getInvitesAndCompliments(forUserId: uid) { (array, sucess) in


            for item in array {
                let user = item ["fromUser"] as! User
                let uid = user.uid
                print("user id: \(uid)")
                DataService.run.observeUser(forUserId: uid, handler: { (user) in
                    self.users.append(user)
                })
            }
        self.invites = array
        self.collectionView.reloadData()

    }

}//end func
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, I will try this and report back.

Comment: yes - this worked - thanks so much for your assistance to you and @vadian

Comment: I know this dates back a little, but I've since had a requirement to `self.REF_USERS.child(snapshot.key).observe` instead of `observeSingleEvent` but since it executes the closure again when a change happens on Firebase there is a crash as I believe the `enter` and `leave` are off. If I remove all `dispatchGroup` code then not all nodes are read. What do suggest I could do?

Comment: If you want to use `observe` _instead of_ `observeSingleEvent`, you'll have to rethink your program logic. As you already found out, the first will be called any time a modification occurs. So, you can only try to update the UI here (add/remove/delete), but not try to return an array of "all" the objects. Maybe you could have `observe` additionally to the existing `observeSingleEvent`, and just do the update stuff in there (e.g. without any `dispatchGroup` involved).

Comment: thanks for the feedback, the function above returns an Dictionary array `compliments` which includes the fetched User `uid`, I then attempted to loop through the `uid` and add the `observe` users to a separate `users` array for UI display purposes but I found got an `index out of bound` error when I reloaded the CollectionView...see additional edit above.